# Face dataset with different ages for same individuals

Tags: faces

for my thesis i need a face dataset where the same person is available at different ages, and possible in more real-life-like photos rather than portraits.

- Data: i'm looking for a free to use dataset of faces with possibly
  multiple photos of the same person at different ages, and more
  real-life-like photos rather than portraits.
- Context: showing how the
  face-recognition services i tested for my thesis (AWS, Azure and
  Google) aren't reliable enough to be integrated in a Smart
  Conversational Agent for Recognition.
- License: free, with the
  possibility of showing 10-20ish of the pictures in my thesis Format:
  whether it's a database with a prebuilt table, a simple zip, or even
  a set of links to individual pictures, it doesn't matter. The latter
  (set of links) would actually be more helpful since the web service i
  made to interface myself with AWS-Azure-Google uses links, but it's
  not a requirement at all.
- Authority: doesn't matter, i just want my
  degree ahahahah

---

The purpose of the project is testing AWS, Azure and Google's face recognition services to identify the same person across multiple photos (with one or more people) in a wide age difference, to eventually include facial recognition in a conversational agent for reminiscence.
I already tested enough with random photos to know the result (that is none of these services is reliable enough to identify the same person with a wide age gap and with little training), but i need a dataset for which i can have the rights to use in my thesis.

Is there any online and freely available?
I've checked some of the ones listed [here](http://www.face-rec.org/databases/) but they all seem to have only portraits with no group photos nor any significant age gap for the same person.

Comment: Hello again. You can give [this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look) a look to improve your post. :)

Comment: that's deep, i'll take a look